# Azure AD Authentication with Salesforce

Tags: c#, salesforce, azure-active-directory

We are getting an error while authenticating Azure AD with Salesforce

> 'The user or administrator has not consented to use the application
>   with ID '1d75cc30-c553-4733-9a88-501e1b45821a' named 'Salesforce'.
>   Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource'

.

We have Created an app in Azure directory and also granted all the required permissions to the app.

We are using HTTP request to get the authentication token.

```
List<String> urlParams = new List<String> {
    'grant_type=authorization_code',
    'code=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(code, 'UTF-8'),
    'client_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(client_id, 'UTF-8'),
    'client_secret=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(client_secret, 'UTF-8'),
    'redirect_uri=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(redirect_uri, 'UTF-8'),
    'resource=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('https://outlook.office365.com', 'UTF-8')
};

String body = String.join(urlParams, '&');

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(access_token_url);
req.setMethod('POST');
//req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setBody(body);

HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Please suggest what could be wrong here.

Comment: According to the error , it should be caused by that The user or administrator has not consented the permissions. How did you do grant permissions?

Comment: Don't forget to click that `Grant Permissions` button for your app in https://aad.portal.azure.com if you want to skip user consent for all users in that tenant. [This one here](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/08/image_thumb85.png) (ignore the comments).

Comment: Which APIs are you looking to access? You're requesting the resource `https://outlook.office365.com`. I suspect this isn't the resource you're looking for.